# How to get access to parent object in a nested object

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to get access to parent object when I use nested objects, I have a complex situation so I can't offer a real example here.

I wrote a very simple example instead, here's what I do:

1. I get a JavaScript object by queryselector().
2. Then I add my own property named `get` to it which is an object itself.
3. I want to get access to parent JavaScript object when the nested object is called, I mean `elem` in `elem.get.text()` the time when execution reaches inside `text()` function:

```js
//***** Initialization:
var get = {
 text: function(){
 //Here I want to know what was the elem
    return elem.textContent;
    },
    foo: function(){},
    bar:{
        text: function(){
         //And also here which is one level deeper
          return elem.textContent;
         }
    }
};
   
var elem = document.querySelector("#elem");
elem.get = Object.create(get);
//*****

function getText(e){
    var elem = e.target;
  alert(elem.get.text());
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="elem" onclick="getText(event)" value="Get Text"/>
```

I emphasis again that it's merely a simple example so don't criticize that I could get the text of input through a much easier way.

In fact I want to know how to get access to `a` when it reaches to `b` in `a.b()` without using a global variable.

Comment: *"I'm looking for a way to get access to parent object when I use nested objects"* what if there are multiple "parent objects" that reference the same instance?

Comment: Pass a reference to the element when creating it: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ft678bdu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the reference to `elem` when creating new `get` instance using `Object.create`.

```js
//***** Initialization:
var get = {
  text: function() {
    //Here I want to know what was the elem
    return this.elem.value; // use this.elem to access element
  },
  foo: function() {},
  bar: function() {}
};

var elem = document.querySelector("#elem");
elem.get = Object.create(get, {
  elem: { // keep current element ref
    value: elem
  }
});
//*****

function getText(e) {
  var elem = e.target;

  console.log(elem.get.text());
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="elem" onclick="getText(event)" value="Get Text" />
```

Also I've update `text` to use `value` instead of `textContent` for demo purposes because `input` has no text content.

Comment: I only didn't realize where does `this` inside `text()` point to?

Comment: `this` points to a newly created object you have  assigned to `elem.get`

Comment: I appropriate your reply, but you know, I'm still wondering why doesn't `this` point to `text()`?

Comment: `obj.fn(...args)` is equivalent to calling `fn.call(obj, ...args)`. In the case above `elem.get.text()` is the same as `(elem.get.text).call(elem.get)` where `elem.get` is the object you have created using `Object.create`. It has its own `elem` property and inherits all the properties (including `text`) from its prototype.

Comment: Excellent, it work's like a charm but what if it's one level deeper or even more? For instance it doesn't work for `get.bar.text()`.

Comment: @Mohammadlm71 You could set `bar.get = bar` when creating `bar` and the `use this.get.elem` but i would recommend to rethink you approach. Deeply nested structures are usually hard to work with.